# Kernel panic initramfs: no cpio magic

Tags: linux, proxmox, kernel-panic, initramfs, cpio

Im trying to boot a proxmox that was abruptly rebooted due a power lost. When trying to boot it stops with a kernel panic. The error it shows is "Initramfs unpacking failed: no cpio magic".
I attached a picture. [image: kernel panic stack trace]
Have no idea how to solve this :(

Comment: The "no cpio magic" error means that the loaded initrd image is corrupt (or missing, I guess). Recovery will probably involve booting from some alternate media (e.g. a live cdrom image) and then inspecting the filesystem, the bootloader configuration, etc. Or just redeploy from scratch, which in many situations is the easier path.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recover the image (it was corrupted) from a live distro (ubuntu), mounting the root filesystem and chroot to it and executing update initramfs commans with -u option to replace.